# Angular 4 - Ngprime Datable - Sort column by date not working

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I am using NGprime for the component Datable, but sort with column "timestampDate" no working ok.

This is the date column:

```
<p-dataTable  [value]="registers">
<p-column field="timestampDate" header="Timestamp" [sortable]="true">
</p-dataTable>
```

The file ts service:

```
getRegisters() {
return this.list;
}
```

This is the json:

```
list =  [{
"timestampDate": "02/02/2015"
}, {
"timestampDate": "22/12/2016"
}, {
"timestampDate": "22/12/2017"
}, {
"timestampDate": "30/12/2017"
}
]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: what is the error, can you please specify it clearly

Comment: Works for me, see this [Plunkr!](https://embed.plnkr.co/2jPgTS6NE3DYIEdeUA8F/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have not been able to answer before;)